# Copy a DataFrame column containing sets

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to copy a column from a DataFrame into a new column. The Problem is that it is containing sets.

```
xy=pd.DataFrame(columns=[2])
xy.at[1,2]={1,2,3,4}
xy[3]=xy[2].copy()
xy.at[1,3].add(5)
```

I would like to get this:

```
           2                 3
1   {1, 2, 3, 4}      {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

But xy is returning this:

```
           2                 3
1   {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}   {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

How could I Keep the set in column 2 unchanged?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that a set is a mutable object. When you use `xy[2].copy` you only make a shallow copy of a Series so the copy will still reference the same set.

You are left with 2 options:

- force a deep copy (not really simple: `copy.deepcopy` would not be enough)

  ```
  xy[3] = [s.copy() for s in xy[2]]    # forces a copy of the sets
  ```
- never mutate a set, but assign a new one:

  ```
  xy.at[1,3] = xy.at[1,3] | {5}
  ```

  Beware: `xy.at[1,3] |= {5}` would actually mutate the set...

Comment: @Radeau: it is the same: `-` can be used: `xy.at[1,3] = xy.at[1,3] - {4}`

Answer (score 3):

You can get the desired result by changing the last line to

```
xy.at[1,3] = set(xy.at[1,3]).union(set([5]))
```

Answer (score 1):

`|`operator to concatenate two sets:

```
xy=pd.DataFrame(columns=[2])
xy.at[1,2]={1,2,3,4}
xy[3]=xy[2].copy()
xy.at[1,3]=xy.at[1,3]|{5}

print(xy)
              2                3
1  {1, 2, 3, 4}  {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```